# Style rails button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button:

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe",  cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

and am trying to add styles to this button.

I tried

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe",  cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, {class:"myClass"} %>
```

and

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe",  {cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }}, {class:"myClass"} %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe", root_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class:"myClass" %>
```

It will generate form like this

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/">
  <input data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="myClass" type="submit" value="Unsubscribe">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ViECdS4KxrTfhazHRcx/6uUp+VXYUUUrqIMNX7jCz24cpeIEcY41IGDAHU1KLOYp2RuwNidxyIKHRlZubUU61SLA==">
</form>
```

For more details have a look at the examples section [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to).

Comment: @Зелёный It is working fine I have updated my answer with the form created by button_to. I have changed the `cancel_subscription_path` with `root_path` just to show that it will add class on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
<%= button_tag class: "myClass", method: :post,url: cancel_subscription_path, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
    Unsubscribe
<% end %>
```

Or if you use form then the following

```
<%= form_tag cancel_subscription_path, method: :post do %>
    <%= button_tag class: "myClass", type: "submit", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
          Unsubscribe
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe", root_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn-lg btn-danger delete-btn" %>
```

This will also work:

```
<%= button_to "Unsubscribe", root_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, :class => "btn-lg btn-danger delete-btn" %>
```